# How can i extract numbers colored green in image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

There will be a picture, in the picture there are 3 numbers of indefinite length. The correct one is colored green. I want to print the green colored number.

example image
[image: example image]

my code

```
  img = cv2.imread("image.png")
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
  _, binary = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary, config="--oem 3 --psm 4")
  print(txt)
```

Comment: I don't know much, I found this on the stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import the image with `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, you are telling it to delete all color information, and convert to grayscale.

This code gets the image you posted, and converts to RGB with `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`

The image is an array with format `image[row, column, [red,green,blue] ]`

Now you can extract the green color, and OCR it with Tesseract (you have to had Tesseract installed, and also the Python library `pytesseract`)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def downloadImage(URL):
    """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 BGR format"""
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
    import requests

    response = requests.get(URL)
    image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


URL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYTZ8.png"

# Read image
colorImage = downloadImage(URL)

RED, GREEN, BLUE = 0, 1, 2
# Filter image with much of GREEN, and little of RED and BLUE
greenImage = (
      (colorImage[:, :, RED] < 50)
    & (colorImage[:, :, GREEN] > 100)
    & (colorImage[:, :, BLUE] < 50)
)

plt.imshow(greenImage)
plt.show()

import pytesseract as pt

txt = pt.image_to_string(greenImage, config="--oem 3 --psm 4")
print(txt)
>>>107018
```

[image: green filtered]

Comment: You can use cv2.inRange in HSV color space.